# When i delete a row from a database i also want to delete the corresponding file from the folder

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, unlink

The problem is when i delete a document from a table it also needs to delete the file. In this case i am using a folder size key so that clients can see how much space the folder is using. But when i delete the row the files remain which means that the folder size becomes inaccurate.
This is the class for the deleting of the row pretty simple but i need a unlink in there so that the file is also being deleted.

This is some info as to how the files are being read and where the file resides. So every client has his own folder now when i put a unlink under the readfile it works so read the file then delete from the server:

```
$pathinfo = pathinfo($document->bestand);
$ext = $pathinfo['extension'];
$file_name = HOSTING_DIR . DOCUMENT_SAVE_DIR . $_SESSION['clienturl'] . '/' . $document->document_id . '.' . $ext;
if(file_exists($file_name)) {
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0"); // set expiration time
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=" . $document->bestand);
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    readfile(HOSTING_DIR . DOCUMENT_SAVE_DIR . $_SESSION['clienturl'] . '/' . $document->document_id . '.' . $ext);
```

Class

```
public function deleteDocument($document_id) {
    $sql = 'DELETE FROM documenten WHERE document_id = :document_id';

    $parameters = array(
        ':document_id' => $document_id,
    );

    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);   

    if($stmt->execute($parameters)) {       
        return true;                
    }  else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

So the Expectation is easy. I want to delete the row and also delete the file @the same time

Comment: And sorry totally new to this so sorry for the messy question

Comment: And what is your question? If you already wrote that much code, where is it going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to delete the row and also delete the file @the same time

You cannot delete the database row and the file at the same time.
If you want that the database and the filesystem is consistent you can:

1. create database transaction
2. delete database row
3. delete the file
4. commit (if file was deleted) or rollback (if file cannot be deleted) transaction

Comment: yes but where and how to put in number 3. tried diffrent ways to delete that file but it is not deleting. Where in this class do i put the unlink?

Comment: After you checked that your statement succeeded and before you return true. If the filename is correct and the unlink does not work it could be permission problems on the files. Have you checked webserver log and the file permissions?